# Schema UNION ALL HIVE should match condition

Tags: hive, hiveql, union-all

so I have been trying to make union on 2 tables like this.

All those subquerys, qwz and qwx run successfully in separated ways.
Are they any ways to proceed this ?
I mean like using other join ? Or what kind of fixing I should make?

```
 SELECT CURR_CODE,
    EF_DATE,
    EF_HOUR,
    EF_MINUTE,
    EXPI_DATE,
    MRR,
    CURR_MARKET
FROM
 (
  SELECT CURR_CODE,
    EF_DATE,
    EF_HOUR,
    EF_MINUTE,
    NVL((DA.EFFECTIVE_DATER),(DB.EFFECTIVE_DATER)) AS EXPI_DATE,
    M.MRR,
    M.CURR_MARKET
  FROM 
            TEMP.DM_QUERY_1_M_FICANT M,
            TEMP.DM_QUERY_1_4_AB_FICANT A,
            TEMP.DM_1_ZEXPIDA_FICANT DA,
            TEMP.DM_1_ZEXPIDB_FICANT DB,
            TEMP.DM_2_ZEXPIDC_FICANT DC
    WHERE M.CURRENCY_HIS_CODE = A.CURR_CODE
    ||';'
    ||A.CURR_NO
    AND M.MRR IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY CURR_CODE ASC,
    EF_DATE ASC
 )
  qwz
UNION ALL
SELECT CURR_CODE,
EF_DATE,
EF_HOUR,
EF_MINUTE,
EXPI_DATE,
MRR,
CURR_MARKET
FROM
 (
  SELECT M.CURRENCY_CODE AS CURR_CODE,
    EF_DATE,
    EF_HOUR,
    EF_MINUTE,
    DC.EFFECTIVE_DATER AS EXPI_DATE,
    M.MRR,
    M.CURR_MARKET
  FROM 
            TEMP.DM_QUERY_2_M_FICANT M ,
            TEMP.DM_QUERY_2_4_AB_FICANT A,
            TEMP.DM_1_ZEXPIDA_FICANT DA,
            TEMP.DM_1_ZEXPIDB_FICANT DB,
            TEMP.DM_2_ZEXPIDC_FICANT DC
  WHERE M.CURRENCY_CODE =A.CURR_CODE
  AND M.MRR IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY CURR_CODE ASC,
  EF_DATE ASC
  )
 qwx
```

Also, I already testing on some ways : hide the || part, (bar part), still it cannot run well.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think `order by` is the issue. Can you please modify the SQL like this `SELECT CURR_CODE,...
FROM
 (
  SELECT CURR_CODE,...
  FROM 
            TEMP.DM...
    WHERE M.CURRENCY...
 
 )
  qwz
UNION ALL
SELECT CURR_CODE...
FROM
 (
  SELECT M.CURRENCY_CODE...
  FROM 
            TEMP.DM_QU...
  WHERE M.CURR...

  )
 qwx
  ORDER BY 1 ASC,
  2 ASC`

Comment: @thecardcaptor can you share you error message?